# highcharts: Y-axis representation without making scales or values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to highcharts. I am trying to paint my graphics without taking into account the values of each in the AXIS Y.

I have seen a website that uses this library and it does (See next image). As you can see the solar rad with 75 is below the battery level with 4.16. Therefore, it does not take into account the value to make the scale. each has its own scale. How I can get this?

[image: Ejemplo1]

My app currently scales automatically and i want it to look like the above.

[image: Ejemplo2]

I add my code from highcharts:

```
   this.chartOptions = {   
          lang: {
            loading: 'Cargando...',
            viewFullscreen:"Ver en pantalla completa",
            months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Augosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            weekdays: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
            shortMonths: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            shortWeekdays: undefined,
            exportButtonTitle: "Exportar",
            printButtonTitle: "Importar",
            rangeSelectorFrom: "Desde",
            rangeSelectorTo: "Hasta",
            rangeSelectorZoom: "Período",
            downloadPNG: 'Descargar imagen PNG',
            downloadJPEG: 'Descargar imagen JPEG',
            downloadPDF: 'Descargar imagen PDF',
            downloadSVG: 'Descargar imagen SVG',
            printChart: 'Imprimir',
            resetZoom: 'Reiniciar zoom',
            resetZoomTitle: 'Reiniciar zoom',
            thousandsSep: ",",
            decimalPoint: '.'
        },
          global: {
            useUTC: true
        },
    
          chart: {
             type: "line",
            //  zoomType: 'x'
          },
          title: {
             text: ""
          },
            legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
          exporting: {
          //deshabilitando el boton de print
          enabled: true
          },
        
        time: {
          useUTC: false
      },
    
        tooltip: {
          
          formatter: function () {
                  return new Date(this.x).toLocaleString('es-ES') + '<br><b>Valor: </b>' + 
                  '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + 
                  this.series.name + '</span>: <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y), 2, '.') + ' </b><br/>'
                  //   return s + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y), 1, '.') + ' </b><br/>'
               },
        },
    
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
         xAxis: {
        
          
           type:"datetime",
           
          
          },
    
          yAxis: {          
             title:{
                text:""
             } 
          },
          responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    chart: {
                        height: 300
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    navigator: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
          
          series: this.multi,
    
          
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate y-axis for each series to each series have it's own scale.

```
    series: [{
        ...
    }, {
        ...,
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        ...,
        yAxis: 2
    }],

    yAxis: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2fd3wsLm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.yAxis